# Storyboard or .xib editor without using Xcode

Tags: xml, xcode, macos, storyboard, xib

Right now I'm on a team and we are working on a project using different technologies. One part of this project it's an iPhone app.

Not every team member has a Mac, but could be very useful if some people help in the app iPhone development, specially on interface. Is there a way to visually edit Storyboards or .xib without using xcode or a mac? If not, it is too complicated try to work over the XML of those kind of files? Any suggestion?

I made some google research but didn't find anything. Any ideas if this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Cheapest case would be to run a Hackintosh, where you run MacOS on your PC hardware. Not sure if that is legal but many do do it.